# How to display equation and R2 of a best fit 3D plane?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have created a 3D plane as the best fit on 3D plot using python. Can someone help me to display the equation of the plane and the R2 of the plane?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) And the perfect question And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service** You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

r2 is 1.0 - [(absolute error variance] / [dependent data variance])

With numpy this is simple, like so:

err = numpy.array(absolute error)

Z =  numpy.array(Z of "XYZ" data)

r2 = 1.0 - (err.var() / Z.var())

To draw the surface you have to calculate a grid to display.  Matplotlib has an example here, just scroll down a bit until you see the colored surface plot:

http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html